# Able to connect to Databse using TNS alias but NOT using service name

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c, tnsnames

I am to trying connect to a database using TNS, and I am able to connect successfully using an alias:

```
sqlplus user/password@UHKGLXXX
```

However, when I connect to same database using the service name, I get the below error:

```
sqlplus user/password@pl0676o.hk.bbc:2006/UHKGLXXX.hk.bbc
```

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Can someone please help me out with this.

Below is the TNSNAMES entry :

```
UHKGLXXX =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pl0676o.hk.bbc)(PORT = 2006))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = UHKGLXXX.hk.bbc)
    )
  )

LISTENER_UHKGLXXX = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = pl0676o.hk.bbc)(PORT = 2006))
```

Comment: What is the `DBNAME` entry in your `tnsnames.ora` file? Is that using SID or service name; and if the latter is it the same as the one you're trying to use with easy connect syntax? What services does `lsnrctl services` show on the DB server?

Comment: @AlexPoole The DBname in tnsnames.ora is UHGLMX1. It is using a service name. Also, I am trying to use same service name while  connecting. And, I do not have access to run lsnrctl services  command. :(

Comment: Well, something is different between what is in the `tnsnames.ora` entry and what you're using on the command line. (Or you're looking in the wrong file *8-) As we can't see the actual values involved we can't spot if there's just a simple mistake or a typo.

Comment: @AlexPoole  I have edited the Question to include contents of TNSNAMES :-)

Comment: OK, so `@pl0676o.hk.bbc:2006/UHKGLXXX.hk.bbc` should work, if `@UHKGLXXX` does.Are you sure that's what you're actually using?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes. sqlplus user/password@pl0676o.hk.bbc:2006/UHKGLXXX.hk.bbc gives the error. WHILE, sqlplus user/password@UHKGLXXX works properly.

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning, with identical DB name and host name, works well with both tnsnames and service name both. Only difference is in the DB name , service name, and port number. Hostname is same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177279/discussion-between-prateek-jaiswal-and-alex-poole).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your sqlnet.ora file.

Maybe it contains:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES)
```

This only allows for TNSNAMES alias use.

Change this to:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Comment: Hi Rene, The sqlnet.ora file already has the mentioned format : SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)